# Apache Beam: read from UnboundedSource with fixed windows

Tags: stream, apache-beam

I have an `UnboundedSource` that generates N items (it's not in batch mode, it's a stream -- one that only generates a certain amount of items and then stops emitting new items but a stream nonetheless). Then I apply a certain `PTransform` to the collection I'm getting from that source. I also apply the `Window.into(FixedWindows.of(...))` transform and then group the results by window using `Combine`. So it's kind of like this:

```
pipeline.apply(Read.from(new SomeUnboundedSource(...)) // extends UnboundedSource
  .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.millis(5000))))
  .apply(new SomeTransform())
  .apply(Combine.globally(new SomeCombineFn()).withoutDefaults())
```

And I assumed that would mean new events are generated for 5 seconds, then `SomeTransform` is applied to the data in the 5 seconds window, then a new set of data is polled and therefore generated. Instead all N events are generated first, and only after that is `SomeTransform` applied to the data (but the windowing works as expected). Is it supposed to work like this? Does Beam and/or the runner (I'm using the Flink runner but the Direct runner seems to exhibit the same behavior) have some sort of queue where it stores items before passing it on to the next operator? Does that depend on what kind of `UnboundedSource` is used? In my case it's a generator of sorts. Is there a way to achieve the behavior that I expected or is it unreasonable? I am very new to working with streaming pipelines in general, let alone Beam. I assume, however, it would be somewhat illogical to try to read everything from the source first, seeing as it's, you know, unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to note is that windows in Beam operate on event time, not processing time. Adding 5 second windows to your data is not a way to prescribe how the data should be processed, only the end result of aggregations for that processing. Further, windows only affect the data once an aggregation is reached, like your `Combine.globally`. Until that point in your pipeline the windowing you applied has no effect.

As to whether it is supposed to work that way, the beam model doesn't specify any specific processing behavior so other runners may process elements slightly differently. However, this is still a correct implementation. It isn't trying to read everything from the source; generally streaming sources in Beam will attempt to read all elements available before moving on and coming back to the source later. If you were to adjust your stream to stream in elements slowly over a long period of time you will likely see more processing in between reading from the source.